Is the prefactor of Schouten tensor purposeful?
The Schouten tensor is defined to be
\begin{equation}
 P = \frac{1}{n-2} (Ric - \frac{S}{2(n-1)} g)
\end{equation}
where $Ric$ is the Ricci tensor, $S$ the Ricci scalar and $g$ the metric. I am wondering if the prefactor $\frac{1}{n-2}$ in the definition is purposeful. In fact $Ric - \frac{S}{2(n-1)} g$ vanishes for $n=2$, so this looks superficially $0/0$ for $n=2$. Can we extend the domain of $n$ to real numbers (manifolds of noninteger dimension?) and take the $n\to2$ limit to define Schouten tensor for two dimensional manifolds?

The only purpose I see for the prefactor is to, in combination with the Kulkarni-Nomizu product, have a right-inverse for the contraction map $\text{tr}_g$ from the space of “curvature-like tensors” on a vector space, to the space of symmetric $(0,2)$-tensors. See Lee’s Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds, Proposition 7.23 for more details (and for good measure, read the entire subsection on the Weyl tensor).

Yes, the division by $n-2$ is purposeful, but no, you can’t the limit $n \to 2$ without first specifying some extra structure.
One reason for the factor of $n-2$ is for the formula for how the Schouten tensor changes under conformal change of metric:
If $\widehat{g} = e^{2u}g$, then
\begin{equation*}
 \tag{$\ast$}\label{eqn}
 \widehat{P} = P - \nabla^2u + du \otimes du - \frac{1}{2}\lvert\nabla u\rvert^2 g 
\end{equation*}
The key point is that the linearization is just $-\nabla^2u$.
If you specify on a Riemannian two-manifold $(M^2,g)$ a tensor $h$ and then define $\widehat{h}$ by Equation \eqref{eqn}, then you have specified a Möbius structure (see Section 2 of this paper by Calderbank, also accessible on his webpage here).
Alternative perspectives can be see from how one constructs ambient metrics of two-dimensional Riemannian manifolds (see Theorem 3.7 here) or how one defines tractor bundles on two-dimensional manifolds (see, for example, the discussion in Section 3.5 here).
The reason I wrote “no” about dimension two is that the choice of $h$ is indeed a choice.
On the round metric $(S^2,d\theta^2)$, the conformal group (=diffeomorphisms which preserve the conformal class) is very large, including all biholomorphic maps of $S^2=\mathbb{C}P^1$.
However, on the round metric $(S^2,d\theta^2)$ with its standard Möbius structure determined by taking $h=d\theta^2$, the Möbius group (=diffeomorphisms $\Phi$ such that $\Phi^\ast d\theta^2 = e^{2u}d\theta^2 =: \widehat{g}$ and $\Phi^\ast h = \widehat{h}$) is isomorphic to $SO(3,1)$ and consists of all fractional linear transformations.  Note that, by Liouville’s Theorem, the conformal group of $(S^n,d\theta^2)$, $n \geq 3$, is isomorphic to $SO(n+1,1)$.
There are, however, certain situations where there is a natural choice of Möbius structure.
For example, if $i \colon \Sigma^2 \to M^n$ is an immersion and $c$ is a conformal class on $M$, one does two things:
First, let $i^\ast c := \left\{ [i^\ast g] \mathrel{}:\mathrel{} g \in c \right\}$ be the set of metrics on $\Sigma$ conformal to the pullback of some metric in $c$.
Second, given $g \in c$, define
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{P}^{i^\ast g} := i^\ast P + g(A(\cdot,\cdot),H) - \frac{1}{2}\lvert H \rvert^2 i^\ast g ,
\end{equation*}
where $A \in \Gamma( S^2T^\ast\Sigma \otimes NM)$ is the second fundamental form and $H := \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}_{i^\ast g}\,A \in \Gamma(NM)$ is the mean curvature vector.
One can check (see, for example, Lemma 4.1 here) that $\mathcal{P}$ depends only on $c$ and $i^\ast g$, and not the extension of $i^\ast g$ into $M$, and also that $\mathcal{P}$ transforms as in Equation \eqref{eqn}.
In other words, $\mathcal{P}$ defines a natural Möbius structure on an immersed surface in a higher-dimensional conformal manifold $M$ by suitably modifying the pullback of the Schouten tensor of $M$.
